# PHP mysqli_query doesn't return mixed data type, varchar and decimal

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function which executes a query and then creates a JSON. It works just fine

```
function getStmtJson($conn){
$sth = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM users");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

}

This is the returned value:

```
[{"firstname":"Lena-Jill","lastname":"Grottburg"},{"firstname":"Rafael"...]}
```

However, when I change the SQL input to:

```
SELECT name, latitude, longitude FROM analysis GROUP BY name, latitude, longitude
```

I get nothing returned.
The query works fine in phpmyadmin.

In the table, name is of the type varchar and latitude and longitude is decimal.

If name is removed from the query then it works.

EDIT:

Full PHP code:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "robin";

$input = "get_spots";

$case_one = "get_spots";
$case_two = "input_analysis";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if(strcmp($input, $case_one) == 0){
    getStmtJson($conn);
    echo "<br> <br>";
    getSpotList($conn);
}
elseif(strcmp($input, $case_two) == 0){
    echo "case_two";
}
else{
    echo "else";
}

$conn->close();

function getStmtJson($conn){
    $sth = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM users");
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    print json_encode($rows);
}

function getSpotList($conn){
    $sth = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name, latitude, longitude FROM analysis GROUP BY name, latitude, longitude");
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    print json_encode($rows);
}
```

[image: database, table users]

[image: database, table analysis]

[image: query, working]

[image: query, not working from php]

Comment: show us full fragment of code, and probably screenshot that proofs database schema name and table (analysis) name and table data content (analysis)

Comment: just to point you use `mysqli_fetch_all($row,MYSQLI_ASSOC);` in place of while loop

Comment: try `mysqli_query($conn, 'select ....') or die(mysqli_error($conn));`

Comment: so what is your input ? `if(strcmp($input, $case_one) == 0){`  ? I hope it is `case_one`?  why your `$dbname = "db";` it should be `$dbname = "robin";` according to screenshots

Comment: @Alex, the if statement is to be more implemented later, it is case_one. And the $dbname was changed before pasting the code so it is correct as well.

Comment: what is the reason to change code before pasting?

Comment: @Alex, to remove information, changed the passwork and username as well.

Comment: nobody care about your localhost password, but anyway there is no reason to change `dbname` because that was the reason I've asked for screenshots, if you change everything before pasting to OP - that change the sense and meanings.

Comment: @Alex, Ok, I guess you have a point, however, the problem could be something in the function since one of them works but not the other?

Comment: I'd bet that the problem is the value "järntorget" and you not using UTF-8 to fetch it from the database!

Comment: @deceze, you were right! **Thank you.** By removing "järntorget" from the database, the result were showed as intended.

Comment: `json_encode` requires UTF-8 as input. Handle your database connection in UTF-8!